How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{sech}x}{1+x^2}dx$?
I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{sech}x}{1+x^2}dx\,.$$
This integral shows up in my physics research, and I see that a contour can't be so easily used since $\operatorname{sech}x$ has poles all along the imaginary axis. Any hints?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411058/evaluate-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac11x2-coshaxdx?noredirect=1
